# Итераторы: Почему в циклах используют != вместо <

Tags: c++, итераторы

Почему в циклах где итераторы используют `!=`, а не `<`?

Comment: Потому что это отношение определено не для всех итераторов.

Comment: Возможно из-за того что элементы, например, списка, расположены хаотично, поэтому использовать оператор `<` нельзя.

Comment: [Why is “!=” used with iterators instead of “<”?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/6673762)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Потому что согласно стандарту у всех стандартных итераторов реализовано сравнение на равенство/неравенство, в то время как сравнение меньше/больше - не для всех.

Так что вы можете использовать `<`, но не везде, но стоит ли использовать не универсальный подход там, где есть столь же эффективный универсальный?